# How to use two objects of the same class during a method call?

Tags: java, methods

I'm new to java, and having trouble getting the right syntax for my code, which I've simplified here;

```
public class Words {

   private int num;

   public Words(Int identifier) {
      this.num = identifier;

   public boolean isSimilar(Object object) {
      Words similar = (Words) object;
      //pretend there's a getIdentifier method in the class
      if (this.num == similar.getIdentifier + 1 || this.num == 
           similar.getIdentifier - 1) {
         return true
      }
      return false;

   public String sameSame(){
      // if the two objects return true for isSimilar(), return true here
      return null;
```

I'm having trouble righting the correct syntax for `sameSame()`. If I have two objects created in a main loop like this

```
Words word1 = new Words(5);
Words word2 = new Words(6);

word.sameSame()
```

how do I correctly word `sameSame()`? I imagine something like this:

```
public String sameSame(){
   if (word1.isSimiilar(word2)){
      System.out.println("Yeah they're same same");
   System.out.println("Not same same");
```

Basically, how can I use both objects but with a method that doesn't take any arguments?

I hope that makes sense.

Cheers.

Comment: Not reasonably possible. If you want to use another object inside your method, pass it as an argument.

Comment: Ok, I had a feeling it was approaching non-possible, but wanted to double check. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively you can have a method `setOtherWord` or `setCompareWord` or something similar. Then you can call `sameSame` without parameters... useful if you plan to make several calculations with the same two words (although I would structure it differently then, but theoretically it is a solution).

Answer (score 3):

You can:

- Define an instance method that's called on one instance and accepts a reference to another instance as an argument.
- Or define a class method that accepts two references to instances as arguments.

So while you can't call an instance method on an undeclared variable:

```
Words word1 = new Words(5);
Words word2 = new Words(6);

word.sameSame();   // What is 'word'?
```

You could do this, with an instance method:

```
boolean isSame = word1.sameSame( word2 );
```

Or this, with a class method:

```
boolean isSame = Words.sameSame( word1, word2 );
```

Comment: Ah ok, I see where I'm going wrong. Still trying to understand the intricacies of Java :) Thanks!

Comment: class method = `static` method

Comment: @maraca - Right, I should have been explicit about that. An example declaration would be `public static boolean sameSame( Words w1, Words w2 )`.

Comment: Which of the two ways in OOP is usually preferred (best practice) for implementing functions operating on multiple arguments of the same class?

Comment: @pabouk - If the first argument can be null, then a static method is necessary (e.g., as in `java.lang.Objects.equals(Object a, Object b)`. Otherwise, either approach is acceptable. (That said, there's some potential parallelism between the OP's `isSimilar(Object)` and the standard Java instance method `java.lang.Object.equals(Object)`.)